# How can i plot ROC curve for multiclass classification in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am doing news classification on TagMyNews dataset which has structure like below:

```
court agrees to expedite n.f.l.'s appeal
the decision means a ruling could be made nearly two months before regular 
season begins, time for the sides to work out a deal without delaying the 
season.                                                             
sport.
```

From this i accessed the headline,brief description and category, And create an 
 array like this:

```
import pandas
import glob

category_list = ["sport", "world", "us", "business", "health", "entertainment", "sci_tech"]
directory_list = ["data/sport/*.txt", "data/world/*.txt","data/us/*.txt","data/business/*.txt","data/health/*.txt","data/entertainment/*.txt","data/sci_tech/*.txt",]

text_files = list(map(lambda x: glob.glob(x), directory_list))
#print(text_files)
text_files = [item for sublist in text_files for item in sublist]


training_data = []


for t in text_files:
    f = open(t, 'r')
    f = f.read()
    t = f.split('\n')
    training_data.append({'data' : t[0] + ' ' + t[1], 'flag' : category_list.index(t[6])})
    #print(a)
training_data[0]
```

The sample output of this section is given below:

```
 {'data': "court agrees to expedite n.f.l.'s appeal the decision means a 
 ruling could be made nearly two months before the regular season begins, 
 time for the sides to work out a deal without delaying the season.",
 'flag': 0}
```

Then i save them in a csv file as shown below:

```
training_data = pandas.DataFrame(training_data, columns=['data', 'flag'])
training_data.to_csv("train_data.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
```

Now i want to classify the data into seven category which have successfully done but i can't plot ROC for each class by this data

```
print(__doc__)

    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from itertools import cycle

    from sklearn import svm, datasets
    from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
    from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
    from scipy import interp

    # Import some data to play with

    X = np.array(training_data.data)
    y = np.array(training_data.flag)

    # Binarize the output
    y = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2,3,4,5,6])
    n_classes = y.shape[1]

    import pickle
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

    #GET VECTOR COUNT
    count_vect = CountVectorizer()
    X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(training_data.data)
    #print(count_vect.get_feature_names())

    #SAVE WORD VECTOR
    pickle.dump(count_vect.vocabulary_, open("count_vector.pkl","wb"))

    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

    #TRANSFORM WORD VECTOR TO TF IDF
    tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
    X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
    #print(X_train_tfidf)

    #SAVE TF-IDF
    pickle.dump(tfidf_transformer, open("tfidf.pkl","wb"))

    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_train_tfidf, training_data.flag, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)


    # Learn to predict each class against the other
    classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                                     random_state=42))
    y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)

    # Compute ROC curve and ROC area for each class
    fpr = dict()
    tpr = dict()
    roc_auc = dict()
    for i in range(n_classes):
        fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
        roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

    # Compute micro-average ROC curve and ROC area
    fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"], _ = roc_curve(y_test.ravel(), y_score.ravel())
    roc_auc["micro"] = auc(fpr["micro"], tpr["micro"])

    Automatically created module for IPython interactive environment
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-6-f23e8ca93b5b> in <module>
         55 roc_auc = dict()
         56 for i in range(n_classes):
    ---> 57     fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(y_test[:, i], y_score[:, i])
         58     roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])
         59 

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
        909             key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
        910 
    --> 911         return self._get_with(key)
        912 
        913     def _get_with(self, key):

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_with(self, key)
        921         elif isinstance(key, tuple):
        922             try:
    --> 923                 return self._get_values_tuple(key)
        924             except Exception:
        925                 if len(key) == 1:

    C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_values_tuple(self, key)
        966 
        967         if not isinstance(self.index, MultiIndex):
    --> 968             raise ValueError('Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex')
        969 
        970         # If key is contained, would have returned by now

    ValueError: Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex
```

Comment: Plz help me, I have defence to attend at 31/10/19

Comment: Hi, It would be easier to help if you re-produced the problem with a smaller example. There is a lot of code to read when you just copy and paste whole snippets of your codebase.